# SuiteCRM PDF Template HTML Formatting

Tags: php, pdf-generation, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to customize a PDF which is defined in the PDF Template module similar to Quotes and Invoice.

The below functionality has been completed:

- Add a PDF template for custom module
- PDF generating from custom module
- Print all Products of custom module on PDF
- Only one Product is printing in PDF file

Problem Statement: I have customized the generatePDF.php file in an upgrade-safe manner. I created the HTML for all listed Products but even though this is HTML it's printing on the PDF as a plain text.

Can anyone guide me how I can put formatted HTML on the PDF? Please, please help. Thanks in advance!